# Write on file Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

the problem is: i've a list of lists of lists like this:

```
(((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) ((7 8) (9 0)))
```

i've to write it in a file, where numbers in every list of lists is printed in a line like this:

```
.......
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 0
......
```

`......` means that i can have more list of lists. I wonder how can I implement this without using loop and using `with-open-file`, `format` and recursion. between each number there's a space or tab and every list of sublist starts a new line. 
Thanks

EDIT:

I've managed to print a sublist of `(a b)` on the same line with this code:

```
(defun write_pfs (filename point)
  (with-open-file (str filename
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :append
                       :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (format str (format nil "~~{~~a~~^~C~~}~T" #\Tab) point)))


(defun write_points (filename points)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (write_point filename x)) points))
```

but then i have no way to print each sublist of `(((a b) (b c)) ((c d) (d e)))` to a different line.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine you can make a helper function using [`labels`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm) inside the body of `with-open-file` so it has access to stream.

```
(with-open-file (stream path :direction :output)
  (labels ((recursive-print (lst)
             ...)
           (flatten (lst acc)
             ...)
           ...)
    (recursive-print lst))))
```

Since this looks like homework I won't elaborate any more, however making several functions with labels that does separate things, like `flatten`, `print-lines` and `print-elements` makes the code easier to read and alter.